# Rolle's Theorem Application

Tags: calculus

[image: I was given this problem:]

This was the problem I was given. I got the right answer, but I'm having difficulty understanding why my answer is correct. Why must it be that "There exists a number $c$, where $1<c<4$, such that $f'(c) =-8$?

Is it because if the function is linear the derivative will always be -8, and therefore if it is a curve it will be -8 at at least one point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result is due to the mean value theorem, not Rolle's theorem. It states that if a function is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$, which is exactly what choice (iii) says.

Comment: You actually only need $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$; one-sided differentiability at the endpoints is not required.

Comment: I always forget about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is differentiable in an interval $[a,b]$, then $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that:

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

In particular consider the interval $[1,4]$ in the context of the problem.